# How to have a list, an image and a h1 all in the same line (but aligned differently)

Tags: html, css, alignment, html-lists

I have an `img` (logo), a `h1` (name of the site) and an `ul (nav bar). Currently, the` img`and the`h1`are on the same line (both aligned left) which is what I want. My`ul`is one line down and i want it next to the`h1`, aligned right. How can I do that? I've tried` display: inline-block;`with`width: auto;` but that didn't work.

HTML:

```
<header>
    <img src="/images/logo.png" alt="Logo" id="logo">
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html" class="nav-link">Home</a> |</li>
            <li><a href="gallery.html" class="nav-link">Gallery</a> |</li>
            <li><a href="about.html" class="nav-link">About</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

And the CSS:

```
h1 {
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
}

ul li {
    display: inline;
}
```

I would really appreciate some help, been stuck at this for too long

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with easily css grid, just add header and nav css classes

```css
header {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, auto) 1fr;
  align-items: center;
}

nav {
  justify-self: end;
}

h1 {
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
}

ul li {
    display: inline;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <img src="/images/logo.png" alt="Logo" id="logo">
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html" class="nav-link">Home</a> |</li>
            <li><a href="gallery.html" class="nav-link">Gallery</a> |</li>
            <li><a href="about.html" class="nav-link">About</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Thanks, i dont know how i missed such a simple solution.

Comment: you're welcome, you can solve many positioning problems with help of grid or flex :)